# Can I run a paired T-Test with two different sample sizes?

Tags: paired-comparisons

I recently ran choice tests for birds, to see if they preferred either food that they have waited for or food that they have not waited for.

Each of the 8 birds had 15 tests, so I have 120 choices in total. I am logging their latencies to choose either side, and my supervisor said to run a paired t-test.

I have two columns, I am putting the first "wait" latencies in column A of spss and the no-wait in column B of spss. I have 36 values in column A and 84 in column B.

My output is the following:

```
Paired Samples Statistics                   
        Mean    N   Std. Deviation  Std. Error Mean
Pair 1  WAIT    1.9167  36  .55420  .09237
        NOWAIT  1.9167  36  .60356  .10059

Paired Samples Test                                 
        Paired Differences                  t   df  Sig. (2-tailed)
        Mean    Std. Deviation  Std. Error Mean 95% Confidence Interval of the Difference               
                    Lower   Upper           
Pair 1  WAIT - NOWAIT   .00000  .79282  .13214  -.26825 .26825  .000    35  1.000
```

My question is: Can I analyse two different column sizes? Most birds went for the second choice of not waiting so the not-waiting column consequently has a higher number of values.. n is 36 in the first output so has it only analysed the first column/the first 36 values of both columns?

I am horrible at stats and have tried doing this so many times with the same output.. any (simple) help would be so gratefully received... thank you very much!